# Scan error on column index 0 , name xxxxx: destination not a pointer" gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am getting this error `sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "step": destination not a pointer` with gorm.

This is my code:

```
results := []interface{}{}
if err := postgres.Db.Table("states").Select("\"step\",\"sequence\",task_name,state,TO_CHAR(time_start,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') time_start,TO_CHAR(time_end,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') time_end").Where("bugreport_id=?", id).Order("id").Find(&results).Error; err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
    return
}
```

The query works fine: SELECT "step","sequence",task_name,state,TO_CHAR(time_start,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') time_start,TO_CHAR(time_end,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') time_end FROM "states" WHERE bugreport_id=1 ORDER BY id

[image]

but it works fine if I use

```
results:=map[string]interface{}{}
```

Thank you

Comment: any data from a sql db is a key value pairs, so a slice wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

`Find()` method expects a slice of pointers to populate the data, and it needs a kind of `key-value` reference to store the results, but you provided `[]interface{}{}` which is an empty slice of empty interfaces and can't able to store the data as in the form of key-value. It doesn't have a concrete type which the GORM to populate the results.

**Why `map[string]interface{}{}` worked ?**

This is using a map with `string` keys and `interface{}` as value and it allows to retrieve and store the results. With this, GORM populate the column name as key and the value which is `interface{}` can hold any kind of value.

I'd suggest to use a slice of struct which can be type safe and easy to work with retrieved data.

```
type States struct{
 Step string 
 Sequence int
 ....
}

// then use like
results := []States{}
```

Comment: I prefer to use map[string]interface{} because what happens if a drop Step column from the table ? I should change in all the source code every struct that contains this column.